# How can I get stdout from delayed_job job?

Tags: stdout, delayed-job, stderr, exit-code

I need to run some external OS Scommands from rails and I need to show their output and exit code to the user. I checked out **Delayed::Job** API and didn't see how to get job's stdout. Tried **BJ** (BackgroungJob) - it has stdout, stderr and exit_status methods, but it fails on rails starting:

```
~/my_src/ruby_apps/ro > script/rails c
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use `self.table_name = 'the_name'` instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/zhoran/my_src/ruby_apps/ro/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_primary_key is deprecated. Please use `self.primary_key = 'the_name'` instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/zhoran/my_src/ruby_apps/ro/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use `self.table_name = 'the_name'` instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/zhoran/my_src/ruby_apps/ro/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_primary_key is deprecated. Please use `self.primary_key = 'the_name'` instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/zhoran/my_src/ruby_apps/ro/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use `self.table_name = 'the_name'` instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/zhoran/my_src/ruby_apps/ro/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_primary_key is deprecated. Please use `self.primary_key = 'the_name'` instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/zhoran/my_src/ruby_apps/ro/config/application.rb:7)
script/rails:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Seems it's incompatible with 3.2.3

Please help me to get stderr, stdout and exit code from delayed job or suggest something similar BJ.

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Am I missing something very basic, am I asking really stupid question?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. I'm trying to do something similar. I want to run a script from a web form and have the output dynamically update through the web page.

Comment: Hi, do you manage to get the job stdout? I tried to do the same thing.